# What are the main dangers to a new hacker crew?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, economy, government, hacking

**Stacey Sparks is a computer whiz turned anarchist**, and has recruited five of her best tech-head friends for her **new hacker crew, "Zap Candy"**. She plans to conduct some **unambiguously illegal business** "in the name of the greater good", and suspects both local and foreign authorities would not be too accommodating of her group. To this end, she must work out the **logistics** of her new gang's operations, including their location, security measures and any failsafes in case of government heat.

Fortunately for Stacey, thanks to her remarkable hacking skills and the generous Daddy Sparks, **she has amassed quite a sum of money.** (For the purposes of this exercise, assume she has somewhere between \$250 000 - \$500 000 USD at her disposal.)

My question is thus: **what are the main dangers to Stacey and her friends at this stage of the plan?** She has heard all sorts of stories about hackers being tracked down and punished severely for their "mischief", and wants to ensure that Zap Candy has the best chances of success.

EDIT: To clarify, this question is set in the present day, and Stacey and her friends are actually located in Australia! (I used USD for ease of engagement.) Given the global nature of hacking, she would be happy to set up shop anywhere suitable; she isn't restricted by locale.

Comment: One of those "You want to commit a crime and get input on possible ways? Ask a question on WorldBuilding first, *for a fiction*!". Interesting scenario. You used USD. Is this in the US or a different country? Current time/ near future?

Comment: Added a clarification edit to the question; sorry for not being specific!

Comment: No problem, thanks for the clarification. A tip for the future: we have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on [meta]. Now that you have at least 5 reputation you can post stuff there. If you want you can post question drafts in the Sandbox first to get feedback on general stuff such as on-topic/off-topic, grammar, possible duplicates, missing information, ... Just a hint in case you want to give it a try at some point. Looking forward to your contributions. Have fun on the site!

Comment: The single most dangerous thing to this group is an author who wants to put the group in danger. I fail to see how this is anything but a point of tension in a plot, making this off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 3):

### A lot of danger.

~This question might be better on the security stack: https://security.stackexchange.com/

There are two distinct angles from which danger comes.

- Technical aspects
- Human aspects

**Technical aspects:**
*Severs:* These are needed to have "command and control servers" in order to control a botnet. This is only if  she needs to use a botnet for her purpose, but since her M.O. is not specified lets incorporate this danger into the full scope as well.

Regardles whether or not your character is using a botnet or not, she'll most likely want to stay anonymous. A government can compromise a lot of tor nodes to bring a hacking network (or any other illegal netword for that matter) to its knees. This happened to [The Silk Road 1.0](https://arstechnica.com/security/2014/11/law-enforcement-seized-tor-nodes-and-may-have-run-some-of-its-own/)

Not only law enforcement or governments can compromise a TOR node, other hackers could so this as well. Which is a nice way to segway in...

**Human aspect:**
We can of course make the assumption that Stacey's skills  are truly marvelous and manages to somehow maneuver her way through the compromised nodes and evade detection by law enforcement, governments and competitors in her field. Her own crew might be the downfall. Someone might not be content by the cut he or she is getting, someone might get personally slighted and rat Stacey out, someone might make an error, humans are fallible, greedy  and generally untrustworthy, especially in illegal circuits.

**In conclusion:** There are plenty of dangers and it's up to you which of these possibilities you want to use for your story.

Comment: Don't forget [the sin of packet origin](http://privacy-pc.com/articles/dont-fuck-it-up-4-use-tor-the-right-way.html).

Comment: All the *[Don't fuck it up](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aprivacy-pc.com+%22don%27t+fuck+it+up%22)* series on [Privacy PC](http://privacy-pc.com/articles/) would be quite useful...